# Prove the half space of a polyhedron in $R^n$ is a polyhedron

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a polyhedron in $\Bbb R^n$, $a \in \Bbb R^n$ be a vector and $b \in \Bbb R$ be a scalar. Consider the set $Q= \{x \in P | {a^T} x \le b \}$.

(a) Prove that $Q$ is also a polyhedron.

(b) Is it always possible to choose $b$ in such a way so that $Q=P$ ? Explain your answer.

Graphically, I can understand that if we fix a $b$ as scalar then divide it by a half-space, then both half space should still be polyhedron. But how can I explain it in words and equations?

Also need some hints about (b).

Comment: What is your definition of a polyhedron? The intersection of finitely many half-planes? Must it be compact?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, it is defined as the intersection of finitely many half-planes. Generally, I am looking forward to prove that a Polyhedron can be
equivalently defined to be the set $\{x \in P | {a^T} x \le b \}$ where $x$ is from another polyhedron $P$.

Comment: Do you know that the sets $\{x \in P | {a^T} x \le b \}$ are precisely the half-planes?